# Input Latitude and Longitude to plot polygon from textarea

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a javascript function where you have to input coordinates of 3 point minimum and them you see it (plotted) on a google map. The script has some problems.

It doesn't print space between coords and doesn't plot the area on the map.

Here is HTML code which I think doesn't have any problem.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Plot area</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<div id="panel">
  <textarea id="lat" type="text"></textarea>
    <br>
      <input type="button" value="Plot area" onclick="codeLatLng()">
    </div>
  <br>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is JS code where I think the problem is located.

```
var map;
var infoWindow;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436412, -70.2685546875),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var bermudaTriangle;

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
  var triangleCoords = latlng;

  // Construct the polygon.
  bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

  // Add a listener for the click event.
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, 'click', showArrays);

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}

//plot area
function codeLatLng() {
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
  var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        map.setZoom(11);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

/** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
function showArrays(event) {

  // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath()
  // to return the MVCArray of LatLngs.
  var vertices = this.getPath();

  var contentString = '<b>Bermuda Triangle polygon</b><br>' +
      'Clicked location: <br>' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() +
      '<br>';

  // Iterate over the vertices.
  for (var i =0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
    var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
    contentString += '<br>' + 'Coordinate ' + i + ':<br>' + xy.lat() + ',' +
        xy.lng();
  }

  // Replace the info window's content and position.
  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

  infoWindow.open(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you geocoding the points?

Comment: to set and show the area on a webapp

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You don't need to geocode the points to set and show the area.  You need to fix your javascript errors.

Comment: checkout this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays) that's what i'm trying to do but with a input where you set the lat and lng

Comment: [My example of how to parse coordinates out of a text box (to markers)](http://www.geocodezip.com/water_ca_gov_GeoRectifyA.html).  You don't need the geocoder if all you want is a Polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you don't need the geocoder, unless you need the addresses of the markers
2. you need to parse the string to break it into coordinates (on the " " (space character, or whatever you want to use as a delimiter between coordinates), then parse those sets of coordinates into the components (on the ",")
3. you need to push those coordinates onto an array if you want to use them to display a polygon

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fkdg/2/)

```
var map;
var infoWindow;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({});

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436412, -70.2685546875),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
    var triangleCoords = latlng;
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}

//plot area
function codeLatLng() {
    bermudaTriangle.setMap(null);
    var path = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
    var coordArray = input.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < coordArray.length; i++) {

        var latlngStr = coordArray[i].split(',', 2);
        var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
        var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        path.push(latlng);
        bounds.extend(latlng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    // Construct the polygon.
    bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [path],
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });

    bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

    // Add a listener for the click event.
    google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, 'click', showArrays);
}
```

Comment: Tha's what i'm looking for, that's it, it's perfect.! Thank you so much! it's running perfect